# Delete this border on navbar using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I cannot delete this margin-bottom, when i get my menu clicked it put me a blue border on the bottom of it
i uploaded the files on my website (too much files for plucker) so maybe it will be easier for you to help !

//solved

the story was : i had a li that was bigger than other and the max height was depending on it lettin others li items with a free space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is caused because the last menu item is one pixel taller than the other menu items.

This is caused by the `<small id="nbDemande"></small>` element within the `li`. If you remove this or style it appropriately your issue will be fixed.

Comment: thanks for reply, your answer didn't helped me because i still get this margin

Comment: There is no margin?! It's due to the height of the navbar. If you set height:50px then your problem is solved but the height being 51px is caused by the last <li>.

Comment: REALLY bro it took me 1 hour to figure it out, css is hell my gosh, thanks so much i will remember you all my life and tell to my sons about how u saved me !

Answer (score 0):

Use `border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(100, 182, 229)` to `ecart-gauche-magasin` class or li( which  is clicked)

[image]

You can also add to anchor tag( in your case)

```
<a id="commerce" href="#commerce" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(100, 182, 229);border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(100, 182, 229);">Mon commerce</a>
```

I will prefer to add at anchor tag level.
Thanks

Comment: thanks for your reply, i tryed your trick but when i apply it, my problem remains and i get a border at the bottom of the active menu